# GUI Java-how to use 2 user inputted numbers to get an answer

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Im trying to build a percentage program that finds the percent of one number out of another. I want to take two user inputted numbers for a jtextfield hit a jbutton and have the answer show up in another jtextfield listed as results. Any idea how to do it i know it needs action listener but i dont know where to go from there. Here is what i have i got it to print out what i want just dont know have to get the actionlistener to work.

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class WeightGUI  extends JFrame{
private JLabel label1;
private JTextField field1;
private JLabel label2;
private JTextField field2;
private JLabel label3;
private JTextField field3;
private JLabel label4;
private JTextField field4;
private JButton button1;
private JButton button2;
private JButton button3;
public WeightGUI () {
    super( "Percentage Weight Loss Calculator");
    setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

    label1 = new JLabel ("Starting Weight ");
    field1 = new JTextField ("Type");
    label2 = new JLabel ("Last Week Weight");
    field2 = new JTextField ("Type");
    label3 = new JLabel ("Current Weight");
    field3 = new JTextField ("Type");
    label4 = new JLabel ("Percentage Lost");
    field4 = new JTextField ("Results");
    button1 = new JButton (" Calculate Percent Total");
    button2 = new JButton (" Calculate Percent Week");
    button3 = new JButton (" Calculate Percent from last weight");
    label1 = new JLabel( "Starting Weight");
    add(label1);

    field1 = new JTextField("Type");
    add (field1);

    label2 = new JLabel( "Last Week Weight");
    add(label2);

    field3 = new JTextField(10);
    add (field2);

    label3 = new JLabel( "Current Weight");
    add(label3);

    field3 = new JTextField("Type");
    add (field3);

    label4 = new JLabel( "Percentage Lost");
    add( label4 );

    field4 = new JTextField("Results");
    field4.setEditable(false);
    add (field4);

    button1 = new JButton ("Calculate Total Percent");
    add( button1 );

    button2 = new JButton ("Calculate Percent from last Weight");
    add( button2 );

    button3 = new JButton ("Calculate Weekly Percent");
    add( button3 );

    thehandler handler = new thehandler();
    button1.addActionListener(handler);

    thehandler handler1 = new thehandler();
    button2.addActionListener(handler1);

    thehandler handler2 = new thehandler();
    button3.addActionListener(handler2);
}

private class thehandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

        int sw;
        int lw;
        int cw;
        double weight = 0 ;
        String inputString;
        inputString = field1.getText();
        inputString = field2.getText();
        inputString = field3.getText();
        sw = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
        lw = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
        cw = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
            if(e.getSource() == button1) {
                weight = (sw - cw) / sw;
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == button2) {
                weight = (lw - cw) / sw;
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == button3){
                weight = (lw - cw)/ lw;



    }



    }
}


}
```

Comment: Please tell us how it's not working. Details *are* important. Good luck.

Comment: Also, you'll want to rename your variables to give them names that makes sense. What is easier to debug a week from now, a variable named "field4" or one named "resultsField"?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that you're not setting the text of the JTextField that holds the result. This is done by simply calling `setText(...)` on this JTextField and passing in the String that represents the results. You'll also want to remove the nonsense text "Type" in your JTextFields as they can mess things up, unless you want to add a FocusListener to all text fields so that on focusGained it will select all the contents of the field.

You'll also want to re-name your variables as noted in my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the results in the appropriate fields using the setText() method. But i have a question for you : You said two users set their inputs in the same time, i mean your application is it distributed ? in other words users are in network and using it !?

Comment: Nah, he just wants to fiddle with text extracted from more than one JTextField.